# Bulk change all entries for a particular field in SQL database

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's just say I have a table called `TABLE_NAME` that looks like this:

```
id  | name  | changeme
------------------------
1   | One   | 1
2   | Two   | 0
3   | Three | 1
4   | Four  | 0
5   | Five  | 0
```

Is there an SQL statement I can run on this to change every `changeme` entry to '0'?

Comment: I'm not obsessed by reputation points but can someone explain to me why this question was downvoted? I think it's clear as I got a correct answer on the first response and it's useful by definition as I didn't know how to do this and now I do. I'd just like to know what I've done wrong to deserve the downvote. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

do you mean?

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET changeme = 0
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I'll check as accepted as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 6):

```
update TABLE_NAME set changeme = 0 where changeme = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like the conditional statement. I'm learning so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
update TABLE_NAME SET changeme="0" WHERE id IN (1,3,4)
```

if you want to update data where ID is specific like 1,3, and 4

Answer (score -2):

This works for single table

```
UPDATE table_name
SET field_name = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```